# Attempting RCON connection for Rust (Game) in Python

Tags: python, websocket

I'll tell you right now I have minimal experience with websockets. I'm trying to implement some functionality of the JS webrcon for rust https://github.com/Facepunch/webrcon/tree/gh-pages but I'm having issues getting it to work. I've made a connection, and it gives me the correct information about the server I'm connecting to. I'm trying to get any command to send and then return the info in my console, but anytime I use `recv()` I get `websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: code = 1011 (unexpected error), no reason`. I've seen various "solutions" that haven't worked like setting ping_timeout or ping_interval to None, but I get the same error. Here is the code I currently have.

```py
import asyncio
import websockets as ws

async def main():
    information = "ws://<host>:<port>/<password>"
    async with ws.connect(information, ping_interval=None, ping_timeout=None) as websocket:
        commands = await websocket.send("<console command goes here?>")

        # Below closes 1011
        print(await websocket.recv())

        # Below closes 1011
        async for message in websocket:
            print(message)

        # Below prints None
        print(commands)
        exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Here is the full error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/rustcord/venv/main.py", line 10, in main
    print(await websocket.recv())
  File "C:\Users\<user>\PycharmProjects\rustcord\venv\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 509, in recv
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "C:\Users\<user>\PycharmProjects\rustcord\venv\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 812, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: code = 1011 (unexpected error), no reason
```

Like I said, I have very minimal knowledge of how websockets work, so I'll take any advice I can get.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent the past 90 minutes of my life looking for the solution to this. I have been to the darkest corners of the internet possible, and I finally figured it out. You need to send JSON encoded into a string, and you're sorted. Each

```
data = json.dumps({'Identifier': 1, 'Message': '<console command here>', 'Name': 'WebRcon'}
await websocket.send(data)
```

It's worth noting that you will receive a JSON response with an `Identifier` key that matches what you sent to the server.
This is useful for setting up callbacks and making sure that the loop handling the Websocket's responses calls the correct function for each command sent.
If you only need to send one command every few minutes or so, though, you can pretty much ignore this feature.

**Edit:**
There's a library that can do this now:
`pip install webrcon`
*Disclaimer: I created it*

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this:

```
def connect_rust_rcon(server_info, command):
     # If you want to enable websocket for debugging.
     websocket.enableTrace(server_info["enable_trace"])

     # Generates a server_uri needed for connecting via rcon
     server_uri = 'ws://{0}:{1}/{2}'.format(server_info["hostname"],server_info["rcon_port"],server_info["rcon_password"])

     # Default
     websocket.WebSocketClientProtocol = None

     # Create the object
     ws = websocket.WebSocket()

     # Standard format for connection. Used dict to make it easier to modify and read.
     command_json = {}
     command_json["Identifier"] = 1
     command_json["Message"] = command
     command_json["Name"] = "WebRcon"

     # It takes string json in the websocket call. Convert to string json using json.dumps
     command_json = json.dumps(command_json)

     # If connection fails for whatever reason
     try:
        # Tries to connect to rust rcon server
        ws.connect(server_uri)

        # Tries to send command to rcon server
       ws.send(command_json)

        # Retrieve the response from rcon call
        response = ws.recv()

        # Close connection, connection not needed all the time.
        ws.close()

        # Convert it to readable json object.
        response = json.loads(response)

        # Return back to who ever called function
        return response["Message"]

     except Exception as e:
        # Inform the user it was a failure to connect. provide Exception string for further diagnostics.
        response = "Failed to connect. {}".format(str(e))
        return response
```

How to call it

```
server_info = {}
server_info["hostname"] = "0.0.0.0"
server_info["rcon_port"] = "28506"
server_info["rcon_password"] = ""
server_info["enable_trace"] = False

response = connect_rust_rcon(server_info, "global.serverinfo")
print(response)
```

I myself has spent about good 3hrs Working library to interact on demand commands to rust webrcon. Very easy to read code if you want to use it for your own code. But if not you can always download the library :D

https://github.com/thegreatstorm/rust_webrcon

Still working on the docs. But if you look at the python code, its pretty easy to follow.